# Does using super to elevate a variable to an abstract super class provide a benefit over assigning it in a subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract

For starters, I hope I have worded the question well enough. If not, please feel free to edit it or suggest changes.
I'm working through a Java textbook to help with my university course and I came across an exercise asking me to create an `abstract class` Airplane, with three subclasses, B747, B757 and B767. Each object of those three subclasses has a unique serial number.

Cutting out a lot of the other parts of the question (which I hope aren't relevant!), I did this:

```
public abstract class Airplane {
    String serialNumber;

    public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + ": " + serialNumber
    }
}
```

I then declared three subclasses, each of which looked like this:

```
public class B747 extends Airplane {
    B747(String serial) {
    serialNumber = serial;
    }
}
```

Finally, in my main program, I instantiated new objects using the following code:

```
Airplane a = new B747("ABC101");
System.out.println ("Airplane a: " + a);
```

Now, the code works fine. However, when I looked at the answers in the book, they chose to do it a different way. They instantiated each object in the same way, but instead in each class had the following method:

```
public B747 (String serial) {
    super (serial);
}
```

In the abstract superclass Airplane, they then had:

```
public Airplane (String serial) {
    this.serial = serial;
}
```

Was this just a matter of personal preference, to elevate the String to the superclass and act on it there, or does this provide any benefits, whether security or otherwise?

Comment: `super (serial);` I'm just dying to make a South Park reference here. So there it goes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Was this just a matter of personal preference, to elevate the String to the superclass and act on it there, or does this provide any benefits, whether security or otherwise?

It's only changing where the variable is *accessed* - not where it's declared. And it's a good thing:

- Every `Aeroplane` should have a serial number, so it makes sense for the `Aeroplane` class to enforce that
- It allows the field to be `private` (and `final`) within `Aeroplane`, with a "getter" to provide read-only access to it as widely as is required

Both parts are important - but if you're not sure about the first aspect, consider what would happen if you had another few subclasses. Do you really want the assignment to occur in every single subclass? There will *always* be a superconstructor call - whether implicit or explicit - but there's no reason to repeat the assignment.

I definitely prefer the book's solution to your one - particularly if they make the field `private` and `final`. In my code, I hardly *ever* use non-private fields, other than for constants.

Comment: Thanks - this makes it much clearer. And thanks for putting my spelling mistake out for the world to see :P

Comment: @AndrewMartin: What spelling mistake? You spelled aeroplane entirely correctly as far as I'm concerned, as an Englishman :)

Comment: Your edit made it extremely clear, especially the idea of not wanting it to occur in every subclass. However, you will be disappointed to hear that alas, the book did NOT make the field private and final!

Answer (score 0):

Also the super() is just a call to the superclass constructor(Aeroplane), it's common practice when making a class hierarchy as (far as I know) that you call upon the superclass constructor. There are keywrods like "this" and "super" which defines if it is values in the super/sub(child) class in the hierarchy. Java usually knows if you simply write the field value name, but it's actually in secret putting the "this" part in there for you.